# curl: Argument list too long

Tags: curl, arguments

I got an error for this line:

```
curl -X POST "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/$REQUEST_ID/response"  -d "$RESPONSE"
```

> curl: Argument list too long

How I could fix it?

Comment: What is the content of ${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API} and ${REQUEST_ID} ?

Comment: Could you share the obtained error message?

Comment: Maybe this problem is related with the one depicted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090784/curl-argument-list-too-long

Comment: could you provide the output of `echo "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/$REQUEST_ID/response ### $RESPONSE"`?

Comment: @gerhardd. It's more likely the `$RESPONSE` part that is the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use @- to pass arguments from stdin ( `curl -d @- < SOME_DATA` ) or `-d @filename` to pass from file.

Comment: For a complete answer, you could describe what the actual issue is and how your suggestion would solve it? (I think you are probably right). The actual command that the user could try, using the variables in the question, would also be useful.

Comment: thank you,
could you put the whole solution here? what should be the line of code?
something like this?
curl -X POST "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/$REQUEST_ID/response"  -d @- "$RESPONSE" < some_data